# Implementing a spherical pendulum

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, computational-physics, oscillators, software

I am trying to implement a spherical pendulum. The Lagrangian (which I haven't fully understood so yet) based on $l$, θ and φ taken from [this page](http://physique.unice.fr/sem6/2011-2012/PagesWeb/PT/Pendule/En/study2_spherical.html) result in the equations:

\begin{align}
\ddot{\theta}&=\dot{\varphi}^2\sin\theta\cos\theta-\frac{g}{l}\sin\theta\\
\ddot{\varphi}&=-2\dot{\theta}\dot{\varphi}\cot\theta
\end{align}

I am treating $\ddot{\theta}$ as the acceleration and of $\dot{\theta}$ as the velocity of $\theta$. Is this correct? Now, each step of the motion is implemented as follows (Python):

```
theta_f = pow(phi_v, 2) * sin(theta) * cos(theta) - G / L * sin(theta)
phi_f = - 2 * theta_v * phi_v / tan(theta)

theta_v += theta_f / timesteps
phi_v += phi_f / timesteps

theta += theta_v
phi += phi_v
```

This works as long as `phi_v` ($\dot{\phi}$) is 0 or close to 0.

[image: pendulum]

If $\dot{\phi}_\text{initial} > 0$, the movement is erroneous.

[image: erratic pendulum movement]

My initial values are

```
theta = 0.8
phi = 0.5
timesteps = 60
L ~ 2
G = 2.0
theta_v = 0.0
phi_v = 0.1
```

After a few iterations, the code produces a `math range error` as `phi_v` gets too large. I have found [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87432/215992) which could explain the math rounding error.

I am using using 60 samples per second, because there will be real-time interaction. Approximated values will be totally fine, but I can't believe that the current state is simply and approximation error.

How can I correct my code to simulate the spherical pendulum?

Comment: You're talking about accelerations, not forces.  There shouldn't be a mass involved anymore.

Comment: Have you tried much larger values of initial angular velocity? It could be that the ball is almost, but not quite, hitting the center in these images.

Comment: In your code, for $\ddot\phi$, why is there a $4$ instead of a $2$, and why is there a $\sin\theta$ term?

Comment: Ok but why the $\sin\theta$ term? I would feel like that would make a huge difference if you are dividing by it. When $\theta=0$ you would have an infinite acceleration.

Comment: Why is $\dot\phi+=\ddot\phi$? Are you assuming $\Delta t=1$??

Comment: @KyleKanos I was going to ask about this next. The issue could also be too large steps in time. This is not a very good way to "integrate" the equations.

Comment: @AaronStevens I feel reasonably confident that this is the real issue

Comment: You use discreet “integration Methode” how you control the stepsize?, try to implement RK4 integration Methode.

Comment: There could be several issues.  I'm not going to pick the code apart but offer some advice.  If you are not using a good ODE solver and regulating your step size this will screw things up badly.  Implicit solvers are usually universally stable, but are harder to code.  Not sure if the angle variable is an issue but in attitude dynamics one uses quarterions instead on angles to avoid erroneous results.  There are special angles where the system cannot be inverted and the direction of the next step becomes ambiguous.  In a sense you are solving for the attitude of your pendulum.

Comment: @Aaron I have corrected the equation, and I have included the values at the end of the question. However, the motion in the 2nd image looks very strange. Would it still be likely that this happens because of too large timesteps? There seem to be fundamental errors here which I can think of RK solving.

Comment: @ggcg So, since I'm not using any ODE solver at all, would doing the calculations in Quaternions/DirectionVectors remove the current problems. I copied the calculations from that page, because I assumed that even my timesteps would not cause these gigantic errors.

Comment: @Leander, you must be using an ODE solver, whether you know it or not.  If all you are doing is adding a acc*dt to the velocity and then v*dt to the angle then you are doing an Euler step, which is known to be very poor.  For second order ODE we typically make a new degree of freedom p = dx/dt and solve for x and p at each step.

Comment: @Leander, are you dividing by the time step to get velocity?

Comment: Yes, I appear to be doing all these wrong things. I realize now how to fix the latter and why it doesn't work. At first I removed that line completely and just changed the "length" of the string.

Comment: @ggcg *...make a new degree of freedom p = dx/dt and solve for x and p at each step. *  Could you expand on that please ? With a link, answer or search keywords?

Comment: @Leander, see my answer.  It may be hard to read but the equations are explicitly written out.  You can look up in Numerical Recipes, a classic text written in many computer code languages (FORTRAN, C, C++, Java, etc).  You can get the math from any of these and adapt it to python.

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Numerical solutions of the i.v.p for the spherical pendulum are now in the C++ program in https://vixra.org/abs/1909.0201 .There are two approaches there: to write the solutions in terms of Elliptic Integrals of the First and Third Kind, and (as a check) to solve the coupled differential equations for the two angles with a predictor code up to fourth order of the derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that you are not accounting for the step size in time when integrating. This should be obvious when you are doing things like

```
phi_v += phi_f
```

in the code.<sup>1</sup> The acceleration cannot be simply added to the velocity (the units don't match!). The expected relationship is,

$$a_\phi =\frac{\mathrm d v_\phi}{\mathrm dt}\approx\frac{\Delta v_\phi}{\Delta t}\implies v_\phi\approx v_\phi'+ a_\phi \Delta t$$
where $v_\phi'$ is the previous value is the velocity.

What you should be doing is using the 4 equations (2 positions, 2 velocities),
$$
\mathbf{v}=\frac{\mathrm d\mathbf x}{\mathrm dt} \text{ and }
\mathbf{a}=\frac{1}{m}\frac{\mathrm d\mathbf f}{\mathrm dt} ,
$$
where $\mathbf v=[\dot{\phi},\,\dot{\theta}]^T$ and similarly for $\mathbf x$, and solve those via a leap-frog integrator, such as [velocity Verlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration). However, since you have a velocity-dependent acceleration (i.e., $a= f(\mathbf x,\,\mathbf v)$), you need to use a modified version of the integrator (which I [talk about in this other answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/240475/25301)),

\begin{align}
a_1(t)&=\text{compute from $x(t)$ and $v(t)$}\tag{1}\\
x(t+\Delta t)&=x(t)+v(t)\Delta t+\frac{1}{2}a_1(t)\Delta t^2\tag{2}\\
v(t+\Delta t)&=v(t)+a_1(t)\Delta t\tag{3}\\
a_2(t+\Delta t)&=\text{compute from $x(t+\Delta t)$, $v(t+\Delta t)$}\tag{4}\\
v(t+\Delta t)&=v(t+\Delta t)+\frac{1}{2}\left(a_2(t+\Delta t)-a_1(t)\right)\Delta t\tag{5}
\end{align}
which you then just loop through until satisfied (e.g., $t\geq t_\text{end}$). Provided $\Delta t$ is small enough, this should provide a more stable solver than velocity Verlet integration alone.

<sup>1. OP added the `timesteps` term to the equations in [version 6](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/447085/6); this answer was posted prior to that edit.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are trying to solve a system of ordinary differential equations by estimating the solution for small steps.  Am I correct?  If so then there are a number of things to consider.

First, you need to have a good estimate for the derivative operator to approximate the future state given the initial conditions.  This type of problem is called an initial value problem (i.v.p).

Since the equation involves both first and second order time derivatives a common step is to define momentum variables and propagate a larger system.  This will help prevent errors as the total time increases.  I've seen that problem in ray tracing codes and what I am suggesting is so common that most people never propagate a second order equation.  The idea is:

```
p_theta = d(theta)/dt

p_phi = d(phi)/dt
```

then your equation is

```
d(p_theta)/dt = (p_phi)^2*cos(theta)*sin(theta) - g/l*sin(theta)

d(p_phi)/dt = -2*p_theta*p_phi*cot(theta)
```

plus the two equations that define the p's.

A simple Euler step would be implemented as,

```
p_theta(t0+dt) = p_theta(t0) + (d(p_theta)/dt)(t0)*dt
p_phi(t0+dt) = p_phi(t0) + (d(p_phi)/dt)(t0)*dt
```

plus the equations for theta and phi in the definitions of p.

This is the typical setup.  Now, the Euler step is very poor and never recommended.  You would do better to implement a higher order method like RK4 or RK5(4), etc, with step size control.

Aside from that the use of angles is sometimes an issue as it leads to the possibility that at some step you cannot uniquely determine the next value due to the system being singular.  In aerospace simulations they use quarterions to fix this.  You can refer to Goldstein Classical Mechanics for details on the math or Zipfel Modeling and Simulation of Aerospace Vehicle Dynamics.  I think you don't need this machinery right now.  You need to write the equations properly and try a simple step algorithm before getting too sophisticated.  I would think that Python has ODE solver package so you don't need to write your own, just set up correctly and call.  I hope that helps.

Comment: I upvoted. Your answer was very helpful. I will just take a lot of time to process the information and read up on the new concepts, which I was completely unfamiliar with. Thank you again for your help!